# Thunderbird: show current column while composing a message

Tags: thunderbird, text-editors, icedove

How do people configure Thunderbird or Icedove to show the current column number in the statusbar when writing draft e-mails? I can not see this option in the 'Preferences -> Composition' Menu.

Meanwhile I'm using `kate` as editor, pasting my user content to the composing window when I finish it.

Comment: I use Thunderbird and the "current column number in the statusbar" isn't ringing a bell.  Can you clarify what you're referring to?  Also, curious why you compose in Kate?

Comment: I (actually not always) compose using Kate precisely to have user control of the current column. Actually Kate shows this number in kind of a status bar. Do you know whether similar functionality is available in Thunderbird? An add-ons lookup didn't throw anything interesting. I saw nothing related in 'Preferences'.

Comment: By column, do you mean the current character position on the line?  I normally use proportional fonts and people view messages on different kinds of screens and different sized viewing windows (where lines wrap differently, anyway), so I never thought about it.  Plus some people view in plain text and some in HTML so unless you compose in plain text, it can look different.  You're right, I didn't find an option for that.  If I needed something similar, what would have occurred to me would be a pop-up screen ruler (couldn't find a Thunderbird add-on for that, either).